# Is there a way that selenium can input my username and password into the browser's prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a site that requests my username and password. I have found a way to use selenium but I have to manually enter in my credentials.
I would like the chrome driver to automatically enter my credentials and get to work.

I have tried to use select functions and send keys but nothing seems to work.
I think the reason is that the prompt looks like a localhost prompt and it is not in the webpage itself

```
url = "http://www.incidentpage.net/members/ticker_content.js"

# create a new Chrome session (NEED TO MANUALY INPUT CREDENTIALS)
# Username is 'Jack Bibi' 
# Password is 'IPN545'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get(url)
```

Here is a screenshot to what the link pulls up.

[image: prompt]

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be standard HTTP Auth and not a login form that requires submitting via Selenium. Try using the HTTP Auth pattern of `http://user:pass@host`... like this:

```
driver.get('http://{un}:{pw}@incidentpage.net/members/ticker_content.js'.format(un='foo', pw='bar'))
```

To read more about HTTP Authentication, check out Mozilla's [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication).

This other [SO post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12892/how-to-send-basic-authentication-headers-in-selenium) is relevant as well.